# mysqldump not recognizing database name?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to export all of the tables of one of my databases "gamestore" located on localhost, to an xml file.  I open command prompt as administrator and run this command:

`C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysqldump --xml -u root -p gamestore > backup.xml;`

I am prompted for a password, and I enter the correct one, but then I'm given an error:

`mysqldump: Couldn't find table: ";"`

I'm not sure what's causing this.  Any advice?

If I reenter the command as:

`C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysqldump --xml -u root -p --databases gamestore > backup.xml;`

and enter the correct password, I still get an error:

`mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database ';' when selecting the database`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get rid of the trailing semicolon in your command.

During parsing of `> backup.xml;` the Windows command processor turns it into effectively

```
mysqldump --xml -u root -p --databases gamestore ;
```

with the redirection enabled, and MySQLDump gets confused about that now-extra semicolon.